# Remove Text from Active Programs in Panel

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, text, icons, panel

In the panel, how can I remove the text next to the icons of my active programs?  All I want to show is the icon.  Specifically, in the example below, I want to get rid of where it says "Disc...", "p2-...", "List....", "Ter...", and "*[Un...", but keep their associated icons.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can short of opening more programs. The more you have open, the less text you'll see. You might want to consider using a [different panel app](http://penguininside.blogspot.fr/2009/09/10-panel-dock-applications-for-your.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am using Mint 17 and this is how I removed the text labels from the Window Buttons.

1. Access Panel Preferences from the settings menu(or right clicking the panel, panel> Panel Preferences)
2. Select 'Items' tab
3. Double click 'Windows Buttons' or select 'Windows Buttons' and click the edit button to the right.
4. Uncheck 'Show button labels'

...and you're done! Have fun!

Comment: I am using Mate on Mint 17.1 and I can't see such an option available.

Comment: Well, I am using 17 as I mentioned. Not a fan of Gnome 3, I mean Cinnamon, so I run the xfce version. I am running a default xfce theme(Xfce-Dusk to be exact). The instructions I provided above are probably specific to these versions I've mentioned. Here is also the config file and line to disable/enable the labels. In `/home/tuxlin/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml` edit line `<property name="show-labels" type="bool" value="true"/>`

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect for the question posed (which was about Cinnamon) and applies only to XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

The default Window list applet doesn't have this option, however there are alternatives. Icing Task Manager is the most popular. It replaces that applet and can also replace your launchers as applications can be pinned.

Right click your panel and "Add applets to the panel." Click "Download" at the top of the Applets window and you can download Icing Task Manager. After it has completed the download, you'll have to add it to your panel via the "Manage" tab. Select it from the list and click the "+" button at the bottom. Choose the "Window list" applet and click "-". Optionally, "Panel launchers" can be removed the same way.

This applet has many customization options to meet your liking.